# How can I pre-process a file's contents being saved into a FileField in Django?

Tags: python, django

There's a `.csv` being saved into a `FileField` in Django 2.2.

Before it gets saved, I want to delete some rows in it.

This is what I have so far:

```py
# A Custom File Field that will modify the file contents before saving it
class CustomFileField(models.FileField):
    # The method that gets called before the save happens
    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        file_field = super().pre_save(model_instance, add)
        file_field = self.update_file_contents(file_field)
        return file_field

    def update_file_contents(self, file_field):
        # NEED TO SOMEHOW UPDATE THE CONTENTS OF
        # THE file_field HERE BEFORE RETURNING IT
        return file_field

# The model that uses this Custom File Field
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_csv_file = CustomFileField(upload_to='results/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

I'm not quite sure what my `update_file_contents` method needs to do to update the contents of the file. Has the file been saved to the filesystem by the time my method is called? Or is it still in memory?

Or should I forget making a custom `FileField`, and simply override my `MyModel`'s `save` method, so that after the file is saved to the filesystem, I open it again, and modify it like I would any file?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the parent class (`models.FileField`), I was able to write this code, which, as far as I can tell, does what I want:

```py
# A Custom File Field that will modify the file contents before saving it
class CustomFileField(models.FileField):
    # The method that gets called before the save happens
    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        file = models.Field.pre_save(self, model_instance, add)

        if file and not file._committed:
            self.modify_content(file, model_instance)
            file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)

        return file_field

    def update_file_contents(self, file, model_instance):
        # Create a temporary backup of file contents in memory
        contents = file.read().decode("utf-8")

        # Delete the file contents from memory
        file.seek(0)
        file.truncate()

        # Re-add the file contents, line by line, if the line passes validation
        for line in contents.splitlines():
            if self._line_passes_validation(line, model_instance):
                file.write(line.encode("utf-8"), + b"\n")

    def _line_passes_validation(self, line, model_instance):
        """
            Looks at line (str), and decides if it passes validation.
            Returns True if it does, or False if it doesn't.
            model_instance can be used to check related fields in the database, which can help in the decision
        """

        ...

# The model that uses this Custom File Field
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_csv_file = CustomFileField(upload_to='results/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

From what I understand, when the file is uploaded, it is stored in its entirety in RAM. Here, before it gets saved to disk by `file.save(...)`, I modify the contents of the file we are about to save by backing up that content, and re-adding it only if each line passes validation.

Are there any issues with doing it this way?